# Best solution for Wordpress site health warning "You should use a persistent object cache"?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, caching, memcached

In WordPress dashboard, in the site health warnings/recommendations, we see "**You should use a persistent object cache**". We have shared hosting (Litespeed), PHP 8.1 with the "memcached" module enabled. However, without a plugin, or other mod, it seems that WP is unable to detect that the PHP memcached is enabled.

Tried using W3 total cache plugin, which has option to utilize memcached. Seems to work OK.

Just wondering, is there a more simple/direct way (like using .htaccess) to enable the PHP memcached for the site without having to use a WordPress plugin?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From what I have seen in extended Google search, a plugin is the only simple way to take advantage of the persistent object cache capability. Note: For many WordPress sites, a page caching plugin is more important than persistent object caching.

Answer (score 0):

This alert "You should use a persistent object cache" only appears with certain Themes I use. I have changed plugins: Redis, Memcached, and more and no change. I will keep in mind what  MrMoxy states.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).